# How do I fix my 404 error when registering a ServiceWorker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm working on setting up a service worker for my site, but it isn't registering.  I get the typical "A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script." response when the page loads.

I've already ensured that my home.php and sw.js are in the same directory.  The site is hosted on HTTPS, so that isn't the problem, either.  These are the only solutions anyone online gives, so I'm frankly at a loss at this point.  If it makes any difference, this site is hosted on a Windows server.

Here is the code in my home.php that should register the service worker.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(registration) {
                // Registration was successful
                console.log('Service Worker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
            }, function(err) {
                // registration failed :(
                console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: what happens if you browse to `https://your.host/path-to-the-php/sw.js` (obviously replacing `your.host` and `path-to-the-php` with relevant values

Comment: I get the contents of sw.js printed to screen.

Comment: just for laughs, instead of `sw.js` try `/path-to-the-php/sw.js` - with obvious substitutions of course

Comment: Wonder of wonders, that worked!  Geez, that was finicky.  You'd think that it would have worked as it was since they were in the same directory.  I have a script evaluation error now, but I can take it from here since at least it's registering.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I seem to recall reading about the path needing to be present! ... I think even `./sw.js` may work, not sure, can't find the documentation (so I used you to test the theory :p )

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution will be to make your file sw.js reachable via https://your.host/sw.js, and change:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(registration) {
```

for

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
```

And as the service worker will be located in the root directory, the service worker will control requests from all web pages from your domain.